# Found an annual pass - America the beautiful

Tags: usa, national-parks

I recently found an annual "America the beautiful" pass with no signatures in the back.

I seems to be new, as it is still valid for a eleven months.

I was wondering if there is any way to return it... is it registered to someone?
If not, does anything speak against using it? Will I get in trouble if I just put my signature on it?

Would appreciate your feedback!

Comment: It looks like you could use it. Pass owner is defined as the [person with the signature on the back](https://store.usgs.gov/faq#Definitions) and *No. Due to privacy and logistical considerations, passes cannot be replaced if lost or stolen; a new Pass must be purchased.* Not sure about any other pitfalls. Whether it is ethical you will need to decide.

Comment: Your chances to find the owner are pretty low - _if_ he paid with credit card, the NPS might be able to find him, but probably not. It's between you and your God if you use it, but for sure nothing will happen to you from the NPS side.

Comment: The same FAQ referred above also says *Note: Photo identification will be requested to verify pass ownership.*

Comment: I would interpret that FAQ to say that the photo ID would be used to verify that the signature on the ID matches the signature on the annual pass.  From a practical but anecdotal perspective, I've used an annual pass across dozens of parks and don't recall ever being asked for an ID.